# pip not working in python 3.8.10 on windows 7

Tags: python, pip

I have installed python 3.8.10 on my Windows 7 machine. When I installed it, I marked the check box to install pip. After the installation, I wanted to check whether pip was working, so I typed pip on the command line and hit enter, but did not respond. The cursor blinks but it does not display anything.
Please help me

Comment: did you try `pip --help`? `pip` is command line and it doesn't display any GUI window.

Comment: check also `python -m pip --help`

Comment: Please check if there is python in`environment variables`'s `path` or not.